# Xcode 7 and iOS 7.x simulator

Tags: xcode7, ios7-statusbar

After updating to Xcode 7, I can't see the iOS 7.x simulator. So the simulator is no longer supported in Xcode 7? Is there an official way to add the iOS 7.x simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You can go **Xcode > Preferences > Downloads** and check, but if I remember well only 8.x simulators are available

Comment: Yes, only 8.x are available in the Xcode > Preferences > Downloads! so does that mean it is no longer supported?

Comment: I think it is no longer supported. Do you still have the old Xcode 6? You could use that one instead.